# nginx ingress controller unable to see my secret key

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

i get an error saying that nginx is unable to get my secret key noting that it does exists when i checked it in gcp
when i chekced the logs of nginx-ingress-controller , it gives me this error : **Error getting SSL certificate "default/my-certs": local SSL certificate default/my-certs was not found. Using default certificate**

```
module "nginx-controller" {
  source  = "terraform-iaac/nginx-controller/helm"
  namespace = "default"
  ip_address = data.google_compute_address.ingress_ip_address.address
  depends_on=[kubernetes_secret.store_ssl_private_key]
}
```

service

```
resource "kubernetes_service_v1" "exposing_app" {
  metadata {
    name = "service${var.app}"
  }
  spec {
     selector = {
      app = var.app
    } 
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 8080
      protocol    = "TCP"
      name = "grpc-server"
    }
  }
}
```

creating secret

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "store_ssl_private_key" {

  metadata {
    name      = "my-certs"
  }
  data = {
    "tls.crt" = var.CRT
    "tls.key" = var.PRIV_KEY_SSL
    "ca.crt" = var.CA
  }
  type = "kubernetes.io/tls"
}
```

ingress :

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "exposing_app" {
  metadata {
    name = "exposingapp"
    annotations = {
    "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"= "nginx"
    #"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect"= "false"   
    #"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect" = "true"
    "nginx.org/grpc-services"= "service${var.app} grpc-server"
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol"="GRPC"
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream"= "true"
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret"= "default/${kubernetes_secret.store_ssl_private_key.metadata.0.name}" 
       }
  }
  spec {
    rule {
      host = "${var.ENV == "staging" ? var.website_staging:var.website_production}"
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service_v1.exposing_app.metadata.0.name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
          path = "/*"
        }
      }
    }
    tls {
      hosts = ["${var.ENV == "staging" ? var.website_staging:var.website_production}"]
      secret_name = kubernetes_secret.store_ssl_private_key.metadata.0.name
    }
  }      
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_secret.store_ssl_private_key
  ]
  }
```

Comment: K8s metadata is a list, so you would have to do something like `name = kubernetes_service_v1.exposing_app.metadata[0].name` for the Service and for the Secret `secret_name = kubernetes_secret.store_ssl_private_key.metadata[0].name`.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply..i don't have any problem with it ..he reads it correctly

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, it appears to potentially be related to the way you create the TLS secret in Terraform. In the `kubernetes_secret.store_ssl_private_key` resource you are setting the various data attributes to Terraform variables. Are you providing those as `file()` input or simply strings containing the path to the certificate files you have locally?

In order to successfully generate a certificate via Terraform and ensure that it contains the right data, you would have to declare a `ca.crt` secret attribute of type file, as you would create it via the CLI as indicated [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/auth/client-certs)

You could try to decode the base64 value of your secret to ensure that it's properly created. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378938/terraform-kubernetes-provider-tls-secret-not-created-properly) that might be helpful in detailing how to create a TLS secret via Terraform.

**EDIT1**
Another thing that is specified in the official docs for using client certificates is that when they create the secrets they are of type `generic` and not `tls`. Could you maybe try and provision a new secret using the commands indicated in the official example? Make sure to also provide the full CA certificate chain for the `ca.crt` key.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply .. no i send the variable using TF_VAR from gitlab_ci as string and they correctly placed

Comment: ` echo -n LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUZTVENDQXpFQ0ZINytSNklVehMGsKdFY1VDZEbUkQ3OG5BZWduTGhhdUU1YUZFKzc0b2FXVEZDego0VDVyVGk2TnZSa01CMTB4azJ0QUlSWWw1c2MzcWZCN1ovak= | base64 -d`
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFSTCCAzECFH7+R6IUxNSRQOguTqS/ivXaoVytMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGEx
CzAJBgNVBAYTAlROMRMwEQYDVQQIDApTb21lLVN0YXRlMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdoZXJv
ZG90MSswKQYDVQQDDCJHYWlhLWdrZS5zdGFnaW5nLmhlcm9kb3RzdHVkaW8uY29t
MB4XDTIyMDgwODEwMjM1NVoXDTIzMDgwODEwMjM1NVowYTELMAkGA1UEBhM
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: i tried to send a request and this is what it says : 
Failed to dial target host "xxxxx:443": x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not xxxxxx.com

Comment: @JihenBENMUSTAPHA how are you generating your certificate? has the certificate been generated for your particular domain? in the past, I was only able to set up TLS certificates for my GKE workloads using cert-manager and letsencrypt certificates for example

could you also please try to generate a new certificate via the kubectl CLI and update your annotations? just to validate that it's not related to the certificate format

Comment: i used these commands :  openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server_staging.key -out server_staging.csr  **and** openssl x509  -signkey server_staging.key  -in server_staging.csr  -req -days 365 -out server_staging.crt

Comment: thanks for sharing the additional details - these appear to be the key + server certificate; how did you generate the Certificate Authority data? Usually, when I generate self-signed certificates, I use the commands listed here, that include the CA part: https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/how-to-generate-keys-for-mutual-tls-authentication-a90f53bcec64 as you can see, the first step is about generating a CA and using it to sign all generated keys & certificates

Comment: @JihenBENMUSTAPHA I've updated my answer with some additional details regarding the secret type - let me know if you are able to recreate a secret using the official guide and create it as a `generic` secret and not `tls`